# How to print sign of numbers in flextable output along with other requirements?

Tags: r, printf, flextable

**Context:** Flextable packages (version 0.6.6) uses two types of functions to format columns with numbers (double): `colformat_double()` and `set_formatter_type()`. The first has arguments to control decimal and big mark. The latter has `fmt_double` argument used by `sprintf` (see `?set_formatter_type`) to format double columns.

**Expected output:** I am trying to format numbers of numeric columns with the following rules:

- using comma (`,`) as decimal mark,
- space as big mark,
- print/display the sign of numbers (i.e minus `-` and plus `+`),
- a certain number of digits

Expected output is a flextable with numbers formatted like `+ 1 026,56` for example.

[image]

**Ideas:**

You can use `sprintf` to display `+` and `-` signs in front of numbers:

```
> sprintf("%+1.2f", 1.056)
[1] "+1.06"
```

But I can not find out how to tell `sprintf` to use comma and space as decimal and big marks and it fails to display `+` in the flextable output.

**Question:** how to format numbers, in a flextable, with plus or minus sign, space as big mark and comma as decimal mark while keeping the possibility to specify digits?

```
library(flextable)
library(dplyr)

# flextable default number formatting
head(rock) %>% 
  flextable()
```

[image]

```
# changing big and decimal separator and digits
head(rock) %>% 
  flextable() %>% 
  # here I use colormat_num because area column is intenger
  colformat_num(big.mark = " ", decimal.mark = ",", digits = 2) %>% 
  colformat_double(big.mark = " ", decimal.mark = ",", digits = 2)
```

[image]

```
# displaying "+" in front of numbers does not work
head(rock) %>% 
  flextable() %>% 
  set_formatter_type(
    fmt_double = "%+1.2f",
    fmt_integer = "%+1.2f"
  )
```

[image]

```
# while 
sprintf("%+1.2f", 1.50) # works
#> [1] "+1.50"
```

*Note: `sprintf` may allow to display "+" sign but I can not find out how to parameter big and decimal separator...*

**Possible trick**

It is possible to pre-format numbers before entering flextable function. But then, they are not seen as "numeric" by flextable i.e  `colformat_double()` cannot be used.

```
head(rock) %>% 
  mutate(peri = -peri) %>% 
  mutate(across(where(is.numeric), function(x) ifelse(x > 0, paste0("+", format(x, big.mark = " ", decimal.mark = ",", digits = 2)), format(x, big.mark = " ", decimal.mark = ",", digits = 2)))) %>% 
  flextable() %>% 
  align(align = "right", part = "all")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-07-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You may use `prefix` argument of `colformat_num` and `colformat_double`.

```
library(flextable)

head(rock) %>%
  flextable(cwidth = 0.9) %>% 
  colformat_num(big.mark = " ",decimal.mark = ",", digits = 2,prefix = '+ ') %>% 
  colformat_double(big.mark = " ",decimal.mark = ",", digits = 2, prefix = '+ ')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is nice to print the "+" sign (showing that flextable can do it) but if numbers are negative it still print "+" in front of it. We could use `i` and `j` selectors to apply this only to positive numbers but it seems to add a lot of code because it require to duplicate everything for positive and negative numbers.